# My preference become null after I try to hot restart or reopening an app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Is it normal for shared preference reset the value after I try to hot restart or reopening an app ? because my preference become null after I do that.

Thank you.

Comment: If the data is saving correctly in shared preference, then the value will be keep alive until and unless the application will not uninstall and install again.

Comment: can you give some example how to save data in correct way using sharedpreference,

Comment: you can check it here https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127

Answer (score 5):

i fix this problem by remove this line from my app :

*SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});*

```
void main() {
  // ignore: invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member
  SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

Make Singleton class of SharedPreference

```
public class SessionManager {

    public SharedPreferences prefs;

    private Context _Context;

    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "YourAppName";

    private static final int PREF_MODE = 0;

    public SessionManager(Context context) {

        if (context != null) {
            this._Context = context;
            prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PREF_MODE);
            editor = prefs.edit();
        }
    }

 public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

 public void setKeyUserName(String name) {
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getKeyUserName() {
        return prefs.getString(KEY_NAME, null);
    }
}
```

How to use: In Activity / Fragment

```
public SessionManager sessionManager;

sessionManager = new SessionManager(YourActivityContext);
```

For Saving data:

```
sessionManager.setKeyUserName("Your Value");
```

For getting Data:

```
sessionManager.getKeyUserName();
```

Comment: can i use this in flutter ??

Comment: this code is not useful for a flutter. This code used in android.

Comment: i need it for my flutter project, do you have flutter version ??